# What is wrong with my argument? (commutativity of matrix multiplication)

Tags: matrices

I was working on my pset, trying to prove $B^{-1}A^{-1}=(AB)^{-1}$. I proved it, but in the middle I saw something that led to this.

$$
\begin{align}
(AB)^{-1}(AB)=I \qquad &\text{(by the definition of inverse matrix)} \\
B(B^{-1}A^{-1})A=I \qquad &\text{(by associativity and definition of inverse matrix)} \\
(AB)^{-1}(AB)=B(B^{-1}A^{-1})A \qquad &\text{($I=I$)} \\
CAB=BCA \qquad &\text{(substituting $C$ for $B^{-1}A^{-1}=(AB)^{-1}$)}
\end{align}
$$
$CAB=BCA$, means in a multiplication of three matrices we can move the last to first, first to middle, and middle to last. Doing the same to $BCA$ we get $ABC$. Now:
$$CAB=BCA=ABC \\
C(AB)=(AB)C$$
substituting $D$ for $AB$:
$$CD=DC$$
which proves commutativity.

I known it's wrong, but where?

Comment: $CAB = BCA$ for that particular choice of matrices. It isn't true in general. So "doing the same to $BCA$ we get $ABC$" is a dubious step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion $CBA = BCA$ relies on the construction $C = B^{-1}A^{-1}$, and is not true for general $C$.

Comment: Can we represent any square matrix as a multiplication of two other square matrices? If yes, I guess it works for any square matrix C! right?

Comment: It "works" in the sense that you have managed to prove that $CC^{-1} = C^{-1}C$ for a general invertible matrix $C$. An invertible matrix commutes with its inverse.

Comment: ohhhh, how careless am I? thanks. After substitutions I never noticed C and D are inverse of each other.